# edittext textview i need change, empty

Tags: kotlin

My problem is edittext and textview dont change text. i tried different methods but nothing worked out. Tried setting text for textview in for loop but it doesn't work. box is empty. can you help me

```
    val edit = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editBroj)
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web)
    val click=findViewById<Button>(R.id.pokreniB)
    val textView=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

    val si=edit.text.toString()

    textView.text= Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(si)
    if (si!="") {
        click.setOnClickListener() {

            edit.text= Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(null)
            val po: Int = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString())

            for (i in 1..po) {
                val s:String=i.toString()
                Thread.sleep(1_000)
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand what you wanted to do, you should use `TextWatcher`. Here is how;

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        textView.text = s.toString()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two linearlayout. In first, EditText, Button and TextView. In second WebView.
Edittext is for number of repetition and textview is for counddown.
My first code is

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val edit = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editBroj)
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web)
    val click=findViewById<Button>(R.id.pokreniB)
    val textView=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

    if (edit.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {

        click.setOnClickListener() {

            edit.text= Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(null)
            var po: Int = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString())

            for (i in po downTo 0  step 1) {

                textView.setText(i.toString())
                Thread.sleep(1_000)

                //webView.reload()
            }
            edit.text= Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("number of repetition")
        }
    }
}
```

}

App work but edittext and textview dont changed. I amnot understand why

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it didn't work. I listened to another suggestion. He modified something of his own, and it works